# installing software terminated in the middle

Tags: installation, downloads, lock, error-handling

I am new to Ubuntu and i was trying to install the restricted extras using this command

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

In the end there was a licence aggrement page which it asked me to agree but the OK button did not get selected even when i clicked on it so i closed the terminal but now when i start the terminal and try to install other softwares it is not allowing me to install and it is giving me the following error:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Please tell me what to do now. Can i resume where I left the installation?

Comment: `Please tell me what to do now` search on AU :) This should still be valid: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/how-do-i-fix-a-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock-problem but there are more on the right hand side of this webpage (see the "related" section).

Comment: Did you try to reboot?